# Require wordpress login to view custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have an WordPress site which requires login to view the page.
I would like to add an custom page (outside of WordPress). I want my custom page to require the user to be logged in (through wordpress) to view the page.

I have setup the following.

In my HTML root i added the following page: test.php with the following content:

```
<?php
echo 'LOL';
?>
```

How can i require the wordpress login to view this page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i fixed it:

In my test.php i addded the following:

```
<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( './wp-load.php' );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   echo 'User is logged in!';
} else {
   echo 'Please login!!!';
}
?>
```

And it seems to be working! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'LOL';
}
?>
```

But I'm guessing your file should also include  and . Otherwise it might not be working, because the page will not have the  and stuff.