# Integrating a Web Page into WordPress with Login

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate an incidences web page made with PHP and JS into my WordPress website. I want only users who have logged in to WordPress to be able to view the incidences page. I add the page with all the folders within the web server, but the problem is that anyone can access it by entering the site URL and the folder name without logging in.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? I can't find anything on the subject. If there is a webpage that explains it, please provide the link. Thank you.

I tried to add this:

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
exit;
}
?>
```

But I don't know how to connect it with WordPress to make it work.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59084918/661872

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the wp_load.php file located at the root of your wordpress. If your custom file is also at the root of your wordpress, your code need to be like this:

```
<?php

require_once('wp-load.php');

if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
exit;
}
?>
```